# jQuery UI Slider: Default Value is not showing

Tags: jquery, slider

My jQuery UI Slider works well.
The only issue is that when I load the page, it does not show any default value (it should be 30), neither on the slider (`#slider`) nor in the text (`#sliderdays`).

Currently, by default the slider is at its max (120) while #sliderdays is empty (saying "Showing the past days" without any number).

How can I have the default value being shown? Thank you for your help!

This is the code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
         var valMap = [3, 7, 14, 30, 60, 90, 120];
         $("#slider").slider({
             max: valMap.length - 1,
             value: 30,
             slide: function(event, ui) {
               $("#sliderdays").text(valMap[ui.value]);
             }
         });
        $( "#sliderdays" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
        });
 </script>

 <div id="slider"></div>
 <p>(Showing the past <span id="sliderdays"></span> days.)</p>
```

**EDIT: FOUND THE SOLUTION**

I did two things to fix the problem:

1) I changed `value: 30` to `value: 3`. #slider worked now (because `30` is actually value nr. `3`).
2) I wrote `<span id="sliderdays">30</span>`, and now #sliderdays is repaired.

Comment: `$( "#sliderdays" ).val(...)` won't work since that element is a span and spans have no value attribute.

Comment: That might make sense, thank you. But then, why is the #slider not at 30 by default (even though the code says `value: 30`), but at 120 (the max. value)?

Comment: Right now because you set the max to 6 (`valMap.length - 1`). the actual slider values are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. You're mapping those values to your array using the array index. I'll write up an answer in a minute

Comment: Aaah, you led to me to the correct trace! I should have changed `value: 30` to `value: 3` (since `30` is value nr. `3 `). I edited my original post. Thanks a lot, j08691!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual values of your slider are zero through and including six. You take that value and use it as the index on your array to get the values in it, 3, 7, 14, 30, 60, 90, and 120.

```js
$(function() {
  var valMap = [3, 7, 14, 30, 60, 90, 120];
  $("#slider").slider({
    max: valMap.length - 1,
    value: 3,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#sliderdays").text(valMap[ui.value]);
    }
  });
  $("#sliderdays").text( valMap[$("#slider").slider("value")]);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="slider"></div>
<p>(Showing the past <span id="sliderdays"></span> days.)</p>
```

So you need to use the slider's value to always translate the array using the value as the index. For example, `$("#sliderdays").text( valMap[$("#slider").slider("value")]);` Here we take the slider value (0-6) and get the corresponding array element.